# How to cache a PHP generated XML file in JOOMLA?

Tags: xml, caching, joomla

I am generating an xml file which takes way too long to be generated and this is a big problem for me because some xml integrations are not working due to the delay time.

I want to cache an xml copy of this xml file, but i dont know how to do this, below is the code that generates the xml:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');

class PropertiesViewProperties extends JView
{
function display($tpl = null)
{   
    global $mainframe;
    $db         =& JFactory::getDBO();

$query = 'SELECT p.*,c.name as name_category,t.name as name_type,cy.name as name_country,s.name as name_state,l.name as name_locality,l.alias as locality_alias,pf.name as name_profile, '
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(p.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", p.id, p.alias) ELSE p.id END as Pslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(c.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", c.id, c.alias) ELSE c.id END as Cslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cy.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cy.id, cy.alias) ELSE cy.id END as CYslug,'
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(s.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", s.id, s.alias) ELSE s.id END as Sslug,'      
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(l.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", l.id, l.alias) ELSE l.id END as Lslug, ' 
. ' CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", t.id, t.alias) ELSE t.id END as Tslug '          
    . ' FROM #__products AS p '              
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__country AS cy ON cy.id = p.cyid '               
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__state AS s ON s.id = p.sid '
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__locality AS l ON l.id = p.lid '
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__profiles AS pf ON pf.mid = p.agent_id '             
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__category AS c ON c.id = p.cid '
    . ' LEFT JOIN #__type AS t ON t.id = p.type '
    . ' WHERE p.published = 1 '
    . ' AND p.available <> 2 '
    .' ORDER BY p.id desc limit 10, 999999' 
    ;


            $db->setQuery( $query );                
            $this->products = $db->loadObjectList();

$document = &JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setMimeEncoding('text/xml');     
//header ("content-type: text/xml");

switch(JRequest::getVar('feed'))
    {
    case 'todobrasilimobiliaria' :  
    $this->todobrasilimobiliaria();
    break;

    }

}




function Images($id)
{       
$db     =& JFactory::getDBO();  
$query = ' SELECT i.* '         
        . ' FROM #__images as i '                   
        . ' WHERE i.published = 1 AND i.parent = '.$id          
        . ' order by i.ordering ';      
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $Images = $db->loadObjectList();
return $Images;
}

function todobrasilimobiliaria()
{

$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id = array();
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[17]='apartamento padrão';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[18]='casa';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[19]='casa em condomínio';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[20]='cobertura';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[21]='área';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[22]='comercial';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[25]='apartamento padrão';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[26]='terreno em condomínio';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[27]='pousada';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[28]='sítio';
$todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[29]='terreno';


$crlf="\n";
$line =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . $crlf;  
$line .=  '<root>'. $crlf;
$line .=  '<todobrasil>'. $crlf;
$line .=  '<feed_version>2_1</feed_version>'. $crlf;
$line .=  '</todobrasil>'. $crlf;


    foreach ( $this->products as $row )
    {               
        $url = substr(JURI::base(), 0, -1);     
        $link = $url.LinkHelper::getLink('properties','showproperty','',$row->CYslug,$row->Sslug,$row->Lslug,$row->Cslug,$row->Tslug,$row->Pslug);

        $title = $this->escape( $row->name );           
        $category = 'vender';
        $tipo = $todobrasilimobiliaria_cat_id[$row->cid];           
        $data_entrega = '00/00/0000';
        $estado_superachei = 'SC';
        $type = $row->name_type;
        $desc = $row->text;         
        $imageBaseUrl = JURI::root().'images/';     
        $imageUrl = $imageBaseUrl.$row->id.'/';
        $images=$this->Images($row->id);    
        $listdate = JFactory::getDate($row->refresh_time)->toFormat('%d/%m/%Y');
        $chamada = trim($row->name_category, 's').' tipo '.$row->name_type.'  - '.$row->name_locality;
$line .=  '<property>'. $crlf;  
$line .='   <id><![CDATA['.$row->id.']]></id>' . $crlf;     
$line .='   <date><![CDATA['.$row->refresh_time.']]></date>' . $crlf;       
$line .='   <ref><![CDATA['.$row->ref.']]></ref>' . $crlf;      
$line .='   <price><![CDATA['.(int)$row->price.']]></price>' . $crlf;   
$line .='   <price_freq>venda</price_freq>' . $crlf;    
$line .=  '<type>'. $crlf;  
$line .='   <en><![CDATA['.$tipo.']]></en>' . $crlf;        
$line .=  '</type>'. $crlf; 
$line .='   <country>Brasil</country>' . $crlf; 
$line .='   <currency>BRL</currency>' . $crlf;  
$line .='   <town><![CDATA['.$row->name_state.']]></town>' . $crlf;     
$line .='   <province><![CDATA['.$row->name_country.']]></province>' . $crlf;       
$line .='   <location_detail><![CDATA['.$row->name_locality.']]></location_detail>' . $crlf;        

if($row->bedrooms>0){   
$line .='   <beds><![CDATA['.$row->bedrooms.']]></beds>' . $crlf;   
}
if($row->bathrooms>0){  
$line .='   <baths><![CDATA['.$row->bathrooms.']]></baths>' . $crlf;    
}   

$line .='   <url><![CDATA['.$link.']]></url>' . $crlf;

$line .=  '<surface_area>'. $crlf;  
$line .='   <built><![CDATA['.$row->covered_area.']]></built>' . $crlf;
$line .='   <plot><![CDATA['.$row->area.']]></plot>' . $crlf;
    $line .=  '</surface_area>'. $crlf; 
$line .=  '<desc>'. $crlf;  
$line .='   <en><![CDATA['.strip_tags($row->text).']]></en>' . $crlf;
$line .=  '</desc>'. $crlf; 


$line .='<images>' . $crlf; 
$i=0;
foreach($images as $img) {
if ($i < 10) 
{
    $i +=1;
    $line .= '   <image id="'.$i.'">' . $crlf; 
    $line .='   <url><![CDATA['.$imageUrl.$img->name.']]></url>' . $crlf;   
    $line .= '   </image>' . $crlf;   
} 
}  
$line .='</images>' . $crlf;  

$line .=  '</property>'. $crlf; 
    }
$line .=  '</root>'. $crlf; 
echo $line;     
}
```

I would like to speed up the xml generation because it takes more than 2 minutes to generate and i am on a dedicated server, so the solution I have in mind is to cache a copy of this, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla can cache just about anything:
You should retrieve your query results with a static method getList() in a helper, then use the appropriate JCache descendant: this is for a module:

```
$cacheparams = new stdClass;
$cacheparams->cachemode = 'safeuri';
$cacheparams->class = 'yourclassHelper';
$cacheparams->method = 'getList';
$cacheparams->methodparams = $params;
$cacheparams->modeparams = array('someparam'=>'int');

$list = JModuleHelper::moduleCache ($module, $params, $cacheparams);
```

make sure modeparams include only the parameters that will make your query change to ensure the query isn't run too often.

Also, drop the $mainframe I guess it's there from older versions of the component.

Finally, did you index properly the tables you're joining? i.e. did you create indexes for each of the columns you're joining against?  The indexes make the db queries fly.

Comment: thank you a lot, i am trying to implement your suggestion, but i am no programmer so it is a bit difficult for me. Should i put your code inside a Jumi module, for example, in order to use it as a module? also, i am studying mysql and php but i am new to this and i dont know how to check if tables have indexes, how can i do this? and finally, when you talk about dropping the $mainframe, do you mean that I should simply delete the line "    global $mainframe;" ? thanks a lot...

Comment: I don't know about Jumi, do you mean Joomla?  The code I pasted is from a module but your code seems a component. There's plenty of examples in the com_content etc. just take your time to read the code.  You definitely need some background on Joomla before you can fix this, start at http://docs.joomla.org/Developers in the misc box there are two articles on cache but read around the site and try to figure out the basics. $mainframe is a 1.0 or 1.5 legacy and is not used in your code (from what I see) so it should be safe to remove. Please don't ask questions in the comments just clarifications